# Line breaks in jQuery ajax html callback cause errors

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am returning a large chunk of HTML from an `$.ajax` call. The string coming from PHP has two line breaks at the beginning, e.g.

```
$data = "

<div>
     <p>Here is some text</p>
</div>";
```

Here is the `$.ajax` call:

```
$('form#form_id').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            var $html = $($.parseHTML(data));
            $html.appendTo('#container_id').hide().fadeIn(300);
        }
    });
});
```

Everything works until I add the `.hide().fadeIn(300)` at which point it throws: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'hooks.cur = fn') jquery.js:1925`. If I remove the line breaks it works. I am using the `$.parseHTML` because jQuery says:

> If a string is known to be HTML but may start with arbitrary text that
>   is not an HTML tag, pass it to jQuery.parseHTML() which will return an
>   array of DOM nodes representing the markup. A jQuery collection can be
>   created from this, for example: $($.parseHTML(htmlString)).

Any idea what’s going on?

Comment: Possibly `.parseHTML()` is exploiding HTML data into array not only with jQuery objects in it, that is `\n`, or something similar is happening.

Comment: Try filtering out the text node and see if the error persists. `.filter('*')`.

Comment: Bingo. `var $html = $($.parseHTML(data)).filter('*');` worked. Make that the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the text node in the collection you can filter it out with `.filter('*')`

```
var $html = $($.parseHTML(data)).filter('*');
```

Comment: Hi, I used trim to fix a similar issue, however stuck on this same problem with another function. Would you mind a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950520/uncaught-typeerror-with-fadein-in-jquery-1-9

Answer (score 0):

My HTML strings did not have any top-level text nodes, or so I thought... I found the issue was just extra whitespace. This has worked for me, and feels better than filtering out the empty nodes later:

```
$($.parseHTML($.trim(html_string)))
```