# JQuery prepend to crash

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

If I ajax any input into my page the following code works but if I print some specific code I get an exception, alert test3 never fires.

```
alert("test2");
$(html).hide().prependTo("#current table.vtable").fadeIn("slow");
alert("test3");
```

I get the jquery exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined
```

As I've said the CSS is working proper, I have tried printing other classes and it works perfectly the only difference is I use

```
print <<<END
...
END;
```

Instead of normal print and the tr is a different class

Comment: Doesn't `$(html)` need to be `$("html")` (in quotes)?

Comment: $.get('test.php', function(html) {

Comment: This answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258924/line-breaks-in-jquery-ajax-html-callback-cause-errors

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this issue after upgrading from jquery 1.7 to 1.9.  This is a bug in the implementation of fadeIn().

It has to do with the fact that the data() method now returns undefined rather than null when you query for a key that doesn't exist.

Anyhow, a workaround that I found is to prepend the data first, and then get a jquery handle to the new, prepended content, and fade *that* in.

Since you're inserting the new content into a table, it's a little annoying to find the thing you just inserted, since it's not actually the first child (it's wrapped in a "tbody" tag implicitly).  I worked around *this* by setting a temporary attribute on the inserted thing, searching for it, and then removing it.  This is a gigantic hack obviously, but it *does* work.

```
var html = "<tr><td>new thing1</td><td>new thing2</td>";

$("#clickme").click(function () {
    var target = $("#current table.vtable");
    $(html).attr("jquery_workaround","sigh").hide().prependTo(target);
    var newstuff = target.find("[jquery_workaround=sigh]");
    newstuff.removeAttr("jquery_workaround").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

For the fiddling: http://jsfiddle.net/BUVUj/

Comment: We just ran into this problem as well, found out that this also works: var $content = $($.parseHTML(response.trim()))