# Uncaught TypeError with fadeIn in jQuery 1.9

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, error-handling

Here is the problem, unfortunately we [have to support IE8](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/).
So I had to change from using the latest jQuery 2.0+ back to [jQuery 1.9](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js).

Now we use a lot of jQuery to load up different sections of our dashboard, we `fadeOut` previous screens and `fadeIn` new screens. I thought I had fixed all of these problems with solutions I found [here(prepend html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621878/jquery-prepend-to-crash) and [here(ajax HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258924/line-breaks-in-jquery-ajax-html-callback-cause-errors).

However still having one more problem with the same error message below:

*Error:*

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined
```

[image]

I've narrowed down the source to the **loadResource** function, which is used to switch out content.

Basically if I comment out this line from the function below:

```
$content.fadeIn('fast');
```

And replace it with

```
$content.show();
```

The problem is solved and we no longer get that 'cur' error. *However we lose our fadeIn effect.*

How would you approach this problem that solves the `Uncaught TypeError` in jQuery 1.9 **while keeping our** `fadeIn` effect on `$content`?

```
var loadResource = function(url, params, callback) {
WHOAT.networking.getToServerWithAjax(url, params, function (response) {
        var $content = $($.parseHTML(response.trim()));
        var $container = $('#dashboard-display');
        var $content_to_hide = $container.children();

        $.when($content_to_hide.fadeOut('fast')).then(function () {
            $content.hide();
            $container.append($content);

            //$content.fadeIn('fast'); // <- buggy in 1.9.1
            $content.show(); // <- works, but no fadeIn

            $content_to_hide.remove();

            if(callback) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });

// CSS updates...
};
```

Comment: On a side note, switching to jQuery 1.8 also fixed this problem :/ damn you IE8!

Comment: Found a fix and explanation in this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258924/line-breaks-in-jquery-ajax-html-callback-cause-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STRANGE!

Ok so maybe I'm a unique case, after fiddling around and going through jQuery and our templates. I narrowed it down to this particular template (Mako / Python):

```
##conditional to determine with the template should inherit from the base page
##it shouldn't inherit from the base page is it is being inserted into the page using ajax
<%!
    def inherit(context):
        if context.get('isPage'):
            return "base_dashboard.mak"
        else:
            return None
%>
<%inherit file="${inherit(context)}"/>

<div id="dashboard-profile-container">
    <%include file="widgets/profile_widget.mak" />
</div>

<div class="spacer-div"></div>
```

**All I had to do was remove the space-div:**

```
<div class="spacer-div"></div>
```

Basically the template above was loading the HTML for the page that was causing the problem. I triple checked the HTML, everything was good there, but for some reason this empty spacer div was causing that Undefined error

[image]

Maybe for some reason that extra HTML node was causing an issue when jQuery tried to render the page

Comment: I am guessing that `$content` contained text nodes, and you are trying to call `.fadeIn()` on them. (Sorry about the edits)

Answer (score -1):

`$content.fadeIn('fast');` typically removes the object after it fades out while `$content.show();` does not.

I would recommend you use `$content.animate({opacity: 1});`

Explore [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more options.

EDIT: sorry opacity was set to 0 (`fadeOut();`), it's correct now: 1 (`fadeIn();`)

EDIT2:

It might be that the opposite is happening you are trying to use an object that hasn't been loaded yet.

try this:
`$content.css({opacity: 0.1, display: block}).animate({opacity: 1});`
or
`$content.css({opacity: 0.1}).show().animate({opacity: 1});`

it loads the object with little opacity and then makes it to full opacity

Comment: thanks just tried that, however still getting that 'cur' error... I'm starting to believe the problem may reside somewhere outside the loadResource function I posted, trying to narrow it down.

Comment: usually if you press the grey arrow next to the error you should be able to see all the calls made by the script leading up to the function you're looking for!

Comment: Animation does not remove anything. The named animation functions in jquery (like `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`') all use the same base animation class and animate different properties.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it happened to me before. Anyway either `hide()` or `fadeOut()` had that effect.