# Error with JQuery 1.9.1 and Knockout fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Found a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950520/uncaught-typeerror-with-fadein-in-jquery-1-9) here on StackOverflow, but it doesn't help my situation.

I have a Knockout 3.0 (the JQuery behavior fails the same with KO 2.3) and Jquery 1.9.1 app where I'm trying to fadeOut an element, but I keep receiving an"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined".  I can change the fiddle to use JQuery 1.8.3 or JQuery 2.0.2 and it'll work.

Here's the template/view code:

```
<div id="cart">
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: myItems, beforeRemove: fadeIt}">
    <li><span data-bind="text: $data"></span>  <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.deleteItem">X</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
```

Here's the Knockout ViewModel:

```
function CartViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.myItems = ko.observableArray(['A', 'B', 'C']);

self.fadeIt = function (element, index, data) {
    $(element).fadeOut();
};

self.addItem = function () {
    self.myItems.push('New item');
};

self.deleteItem = function (item) {
    self.myItems.remove(item);
};

}

var vm = new CartViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("cart"));
```

I've created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qTvs9/) to demonstrate such behavior.

Looking for some creative workarounds

Some things I've already tried:

- using JQuery animate on *$el.css({opacity: 1, display: 'block'}).animate({opacity: 0}), which failed with the same error
- I've tried putting in a $.delay() to see if I could defer the fadeOut() until a future frame

Thanks for any suggestions. Ideally, we'd not switch to JQuery 2.0+

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems that the element is not what you really think it is, I looking at $(element) it is not the li element which is a problem in your case

`$(element).next().fadeOut();`

seems to work but I'm betting you'll need a more concrete way of getting to that li

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qTvs9/1/

Comment: I've experimented with siblings(), parent(), etc.  I think part of the issue is that Knockout leaves some templating DOM in there?, but when I view $(element) in the Chrome Debugger, it is attached to the correct item.

Comment: When I try deleting "A" in your code, it deletes both "A" & "B", BTW. Though when I inspect $(e).next() in the debug code, it seems to be showing the proper element.

Comment: @taudep yeah again that might be caused by the $(element).next().fadeOut() not really capturing the correct element updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qTvs9/2/ this doesn't rely on the fade it(it does it in the delete)