# Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element' error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with some inherited code - it is a wall app something like FB where registered users can post topics. A lot of the code is JS and jQuery and I know little about either.

When posting a topic the topic gets added to the database but the screen does not show the topic until it is refreshed but it should show immediately - when I look in Developer Tools I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
```

When I expand the error I get:

```
curCSS  @   jquery-1.8.3.js:6825
jQuery.extend.css   @   jquery-1.8.3.js:6782
isHidden    @   jquery-1.8.3.js:6587
defaultPrefilter    @   jquery-1.8.3.js:8797
Animation   @   jquery-1.8.3.js:8697
doAnimation @   jquery-1.8.3.js:9034
jQuery.extend.dequeue   @   jquery-1.8.3.js:1895
(anonymous function)    @   jquery-1.8.3.js:1938
jQuery.extend.each  @   jquery-1.8.3.js:611
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each   @   jquery-1.8.3.js:241
jQuery.fn.extend.queue  @   jquery-1.8.3.js:1931
jQuery.fn.extend.animate    @   jquery-1.8.3.js:9044
jQuery.fn.(anonymous function)  @   jquery-1.8.3.js:9129
(anonymous function)    @   script.js:52
fire    @   jquery-1.8.3.js:974
self.fireWith   @   jquery-1.8.3.js:1084
done    @   jquery-1.8.3.js:7803
callback    @   jquery-1.8.3.js:8518
```

Line 52 in script.js is:

```
$('#loadpage').prepend($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
```

I am hoping this isn't something fixed in jQuery 1.9.x and above as upgrading breaks too many things at the moment to make it viable but I have no idea where to begin troubleshooting this

I found three questions with the same error but wasn't able to get any ideas from the answers probably due to mylack of JS knowledge.

Have made some progress - I updated to jQUery 1.9.1 and this time the same happened but the error changed. This time the error became:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined
```

pointing to the same line in script.js

A quick search found [Uncaught TypeError with fadeIn in jQuery 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950520/uncaught-typeerror-with-fadein-in-jquery-1-9) which recommended changing the line:

```
$('#loadpage').prepend($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
```

to:

```
$('#loadpage').prepend($(response).show());
```

When I do this there are no longer any errors but it still does not quite work correctly - when the new post is posted there is a new entry added to the list but it is a duplicate of the previous post. So for example,

```
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
```

If I post a new post called Post 4 then it displays as:

```
Post 1
Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
```

When I refresh it then shows correctly as Post 4 etc so feels like some progress but still not quite there

Response is defined in:

```
    $('#post').click(function(){
        var a = $("#wm").val();
        if(a != "")
        {
            var keepID = $('#keepID').val();
            var posted_on = $('#posted_on').val();

            $.post("wall.php?value="+a+'&x='+keepID+'&p='+posted_on, {
            }, function(response){
                //console.log(response);        

                //$('#load').prepend($(response).fadeIn('slow'));
                $('#load').prepend($(response).show());
                $("#wm").val("");
            });
        }


    });
```

This script is fricking horrific!

Comment: Line numbers would be more useful if you used [unminified jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js).

Comment: Excellent point, I will sort that now - thank you

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint there and inspect the value of `response`?

Comment: The problem is that response doesn't exist. In Your version on JQ this error seems not to be catched. So the issue isn't on that line. I'll need more context.

Comment: Guys - can you give me any pointers on how to get that information? My JS knowledge is weak to zero!

Comment: You could just paste the whole script to [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: What does `response` contains exactly ?

Comment: It should contain the HTML for the new comment but when I log it to the console it is actually showing me the HTML of the previous comment including the "correct" post ID of that previous comment

Comment: Your problem with fadeIn probably has the same origin as the one you have now. Can you post the lines where `response` is defined?

Comment: Can you post, what your `response` actually looks like? I would guess, you're having some kind of invalid html.

Comment: I had same issue and it got fixed by the method mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29841371/524700

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to insert the element before showing it. Try this:

```
$('#post').click(function(){
    var a = $("#wm").val();
    if(a != "")
    {
        var keepID = $('#keepID').val();
        var posted_on = $('#posted_on').val();

        $.post("wall.php?value="+a+'&x='+keepID+'&p='+posted_on, {
        }, function(response){
            $(response).prependTo($('#load')).fadeIn('slow');
            $("#wm").val("");
        });
    }
});
```

If that doesn't work, there must be an error in the **php script** or in **the GET params you are passing**